# Python: Wait on all of `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`'s futures

Tags: python, concurrency, future

I've given `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` a bunch of tasks, and I want to wait until they're all completed before proceeding with the flow. How can I do that, without having to save all the futures and call `wait` on them? (I want an action on the executor.)

Comment: the executor has no concept of when it is done executing, that is the domain of the `Future` object.  Can you explain further why you don't want to use `Future` methods?  There's a number of different ways to do it (one of them being `wait` as you pointed out).

Comment: @roippi Actually *it does*. See my answer. However it's not probably what the OP expects.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Just call [`Executor.shutdown`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.shutdown):

> **`shutdown(wait=True)`**
>
> Signal the executor that it should free any resources that it is
>   using *when the currently pending futures are done executing*. Calls
>   to `Executor.submit()` and `Executor.map()` made after shutdown will
>   raise `RuntimeError`.
>
> If wait is `True` then this method will not return until all the pending futures are
>   done executing and the resources associated with the executor have been freed.

However if you keep track of your futures in a list then you can avoid shutting the executor down for future use using the [`futures.wait()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.wait) function:

> **`concurrent.futures.wait(fs, timeout=None, return_when=ALL_COMPLETED)`**
>
> Wait for the `Future` instances (possibly created by different
>   `Executor` instances) given by `fs` to complete. Returns a named 2-tuple
>   of sets. The first set, named done, contains the futures that
>   completed (finished or were cancelled) before the wait completed. The
>   second set, named not_done, contains uncompleted futures.

note that if you don't provide a `timeout` it waits until all futures have completed.

You can also use [`futures.as_completed()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.as_completed) instead, however you'd have to iterate over it.

Comment: So you're saying that if I use the executor as a context manager, then after the suite finishes, it'll wait until all futures are done, even if there are 10,000 of them and only 10 workers?

Comment: @RamRachum Yes. From the documentation: "You can avoid having to call this method explicitly if you use the with statement, which will shutdown the `Executor` (waiting as if `Executor.shutdown()` were called with wait set to `True`):".

Comment: Does shutdown(wait=True) wait for callbacks of the future too?

Comment: if you are using the with statement, then shutdown is called automatically.

Comment: @ospider in my experience the executor isn't usually used as context manager because it is used from different parts of the code.

Comment: Note this can't be used when the "top-level" futures might add "children" futures to the same pool as they run. `RuntimeError('cannot schedule new futures after shutdown',)` Sigh.

Answer (score 27):

As stated before, one can use [`Executor.shutdown(wait=True)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.shutdown), but also pay attention to the following note in the documentation:

> You can **avoid having to call this method explicitly** if you use the `with` statement, which will shutdown the `Executor` (waiting as if `Executor.shutdown()` were called with *`wait`* set to `True`):
>
> ```py
> import shutil
> with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as e:
>     e.submit(shutil.copy, 'src1.txt', 'dest1.txt')
>     e.submit(shutil.copy, 'src2.txt', 'dest2.txt')
>     e.submit(shutil.copy, 'src3.txt', 'dest3.txt')
>     e.submit(shutil.copy, 'src4.txt', 'dest4.txt')
> ```

Answer (score 19):

Bakuriu's answer is correct. Just to extend a little bit. As we all know a context manager has `__enter__` and `__exit__` method. Here is how `class Executor`(**ThreadPoolExecutor's base class**) is defined

```
class Executor(object):

    # other methods

    def shutdown(self, wait=True):
        """Clean-up the resources associated with the Executor.

        It is safe to call this method several times. Otherwise, no other
        methods can be called after this one.

        Args:
            wait: If True then shutdown will not return until all running
                futures have finished executing and the resources used by the
                executor have been reclaimed.
        """
        pass

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.shutdown(wait=True)
        return False
```

And it is `ThreadPoolExecutor` that actually defines the `shutdown` method

```
class ThreadPoolExecutor(_base.Executor):
    def shutdown(self, wait=True):
        with self._shutdown_lock:
            self._shutdown = True
            self._work_queue.put(None)
        if wait:
            for t in self._threads:
                t.join()
```

Comment: as the name implies, this yields results *as they are completed*, i.e. it does not wait for the whole pool of tasks to finish, as the OP requested.

Comment: @roippi If you know how many tasks there are, why not count the number of finished tasks? But that being said, there is no guarantee the program knows the number of concurrent tasks.

Comment: @roippi what is the different between completed and finished?

Comment: What would happen if we just wrote `for t in executor._threads: t.join()` without any other code (i.e., without shutting down the Executor)? I know it wouldn't be legal anyway since _threads isn't public API, but I'm trying to understand the logic of thread creation/destruction in the Executor. Could this potentially hang forever since new tasks are added to the executor, preventing the threads from ever finishing?