# Python Concurrency: Wait for one out of few futures and cancel the rest

Tags: python, python-3.x, concurrency

I am usually using `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` for executing tasks concurrently in python.

There is a function that is very lengthy and non-deterministic in terms of the time it takes to be executed (it gets a proxy, send an HTTP request, etc.).

I want to call it few times (let's say 2), and here is when it gets complicated for me:

When **one** of the tasks finishes, I would like to check its return value and if it's True, carry on with the code-path and i don't care anymore about the second task and there is no need to wait for it anymore.

But if the return value is False, I would like to wait for the second task to finish and then continue with the code-path.

I tried to look in several places here in SO, like this [python concurrency question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21143162/python-wait-on-all-of-concurrent-futures-threadpoolexecutors-futures#) but still couldn't understand how to do it precisely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use concurrent.futures.wait with the return_when=FIRST_COMPLETED option (which will wait on multiple futures, but return as soon as any of them complete).  But even simpler is to use concurrent.futures.as_completed, which gives you an iterator that returns the futures as they complete or are cancelled.

```
f1 = executor.submit(job_1)
f2 = executor.submit(job_2)
for f in concurrent.futures.as_completed((f1,f2)):
  if f.completed() and f.result():
    # a job completed and returned True, so skip the rest
    break
else:
  # handle case where none of the tasks succeeded
  pass
# normal code path
```