# concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() is missing some files to process

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-files, multicore, concurrent.futures

I am using Python (v 3.7.0) and have more than 17 770 text files to process. I need to have a separate row for each file and then put the data of files into a pandas DataFrame (**Y**) in separate columns based on the data. To fasten the process I am using `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor()` but it looks like to miss some files from processing.

```
def lineProcess(file):
   #This function takes a single file as input and processes it line by line
   #It simultaneously adds the relevant data in the pandas DataFrame Y
   with open(file) as f:
   #a takes the first line of each file which will be the row of DataFrame Y
      a = int(f.readline().split(':')[0])
      for line in f.readlines():
      #Now reading from 2nd line onwards
         b = int(line.split(',')[0])
         c= int(line.split(',')[1])
         #Y is the DataFrame in which the data needs to be stored
         Y.loc[str(a), str(b)] = c

def fileProcess():
   #This function makes the call to function lineProcess() for each file
   import glob2
   fileslist = glob2.glob("*.txt")
   import concurrent.futures
   with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
      executor.map(lineProcess, fileslist)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   #Main fnction to make the call to fileProcess function()
   import pandas
   global Y
   Y = pandas.DataFrame()
   fileProcess()
   print(Y)
```

Now, to test the program, I have run it using 5 text files only (`fileslist[:] = fileslist[0:5]`). Suppose the text files are: (`textfile1.txt, textfile2.txt, textfile3.txt, textfile4.txt, textfile5.txt`) and the first line of each text file (which corresponds to one row of the DataFrame Y) be the numbers `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` i,e, the data of the 1st file will be in the row with `rowname` `1`, that of the second file in the row with `rowname` `2` and so on.
Now after running above program, the output is as follows *(I am showing two outputs corresponding to running the code two times)*:

```
   2059652  1666394  1759415   ...     1687086  1188337  2100070
2      4.0      3.0      4.0   ...         NaN      NaN      NaN
1      NaN      NaN      NaN   ...         NaN      NaN      NaN
3      NaN      NaN      NaN   ...         NaN      NaN      NaN
5      NaN      NaN      NaN   ...         5.0      4.0      1.0

   1065039  1544320  410199  732556   ...     2317644  1687086  1188337  2100070
1      NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN   ...         NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
4      3.0      1.0     5.0     NaN   ...         NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
2      NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN   ...         NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
5      NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN   ...         5.0      5.0      4.0      1.0
```

The order of row (`2, 1, 3, 5` or `1, 4, 2, 5`) is random and changes everytime I run above program but **notice** that the code here has missed filling the data corresponding to file no. `textfile4.txt` *(row with name 4 is missing)* in the first run and `textfile3.txt` *(row with name 3 is missing)* in the second run.
A sample of text files I am processing is as follows (say `textfile1.txt`):

```
1:
1488844,3
822109,5
885013,4
30878,4
...(#so on)
```

Comment: It seems likely that the parallel process has not finished by the time you reach the print statement. Remember that the executor is running asynchronous. [This related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21143162/python-wait-on-all-of-concurrent-futures-threadpoolexecutors-futures) should prove useful.

Comment: @BramVanroy I read the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21143809/7698116) you mentioned and read about the **executor.shutdown** [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.shutdown). It is mentioned there that "_You can avoid having to call this method (`shutdown`) explicitly if you use the `with` statement, which will shutdown the Executor (waiting as if `Executor.shutdown()` were called with wait set to True)_". Also, I tried putting executor.shudown explicitly in my code but it didn't help. Thank You.